# Why does 0x8FFFFFF equal 128MB?

Tags: hex

I sometimes see code like this:

```
int length = 0x8FFFFFF; //128MB
byte buf = new byte[length];
```

It does not make much sense to me as:

0x8FFFFFF = 150,994,943
128MB = 128 * 1024 * 1024 byte = 134,217,728 byte

These two number does not equal. What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone previously had a `7` there but changed it to a `8` in order to avoid an off-by-one error, but forgot to change the rest to `0`.

Comment: Heh. That's probably the most likely explanation. 7FFFFFF is (128MB - 1).

Answer (score 0):

Well, 0x7FFFFFF = 134217727, so 128MB should be 0x8000000